# how to see what went wrong ("There was a problem.. report it)

Tags: apport

How do I know what went wrong when "There was a problem.. report" box comes up every time I boot.  How to stop the repeats after I "report" this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug. I assume that you're using 19.04. Once you report a crash, it should clean up the crash files so that you don't see the same crash dialog again.

While viewing the crash dialog, you can flip down the `details` arrow to get the technical information about **what went wrong**.

Once you've reported it, to **stop the repeats**, we clear out the obsolete crash files, in `terminal`, type:

`cd /var/crash` # change directories

`ls -al` # see the various crash logs

`sudo rm *.crash` # delete obsolete crash files

Comment: There is not detail thing.  just report problem and cancel.  I give up.. what to do.. Yes I'm running Mate 19.04

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti You asked the question "How do I know what went wrong", and " How to stop the repeats", and I answered both questions. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Well, deleting the files did solve my problem, thanks.  But there was no detail button the the report dialog.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti it's not a button, but a small sideways triangle... and I think it says "details" or "more information" next to it.